# Using Material-UI's useStyle in helper functions or making helper functions behave like functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

```
Line 20:21:  React Hook "useStyles" is called in function "renderActions" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I am getting the following error, but I am not sure why I am getting it. Isn't `renderAction` a function component since we're rendering jsx? What can we do to make it behave like a function component then? I am asking because I would like to use the helper function as a function component so I can use Material-UI's `useStyle` instead of using the style properties and avoid unnecessary code repeat.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  },
  modal: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
}));

const renderActions = (deleteVideo, id) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button onClick={() => deleteVideo(id)} className={classes.button}>Delete</Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}


const Delete = (props) => {
  const {deleteVideo, id } = props;
  return (
    <Modal 
      className={classes.modal}
      actions={renderActions(deleteVideo, id)}
    />
  )
}
```

Is there perhaps a better way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to Capitalize 'R' of the renderAction function. That is why you are getting this error. All react Component functions start with Capital Letters.
Make it like this:

```
const RenderActions = (props) => {   const classes = useStyles();   return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button
        onClick={() => props.deleteVideo(props.id)}
        className={classes.button}
      >
        Delete
      </Button>
    </React.Fragment>   ); };
```

In your delete function you failed to define the style so you are getting another error. Add the styles.

```
const Delete = (props) => {
  const { deleteVideo, id } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Modal className={classes.modal} actions={RenderActions(deleteVideo, id)} />
  );
};
```